# How to detect or estimate the age of a photo?

Tags: prints, print-preservation, old-prints

So I got this (old?) photo right here (shown below, face hidden) and I want to estimate how old it is, any clues? It already looks noisy and low-quality to be recent, so what can I do to find the age? I can provide other pics if needed. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Is this a physical photograph on paper, or a digital computer file?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Physical

Comment: I may be wrong though as I only have that image JPG now nothing else

Answer (score 3):

Clothing, hair, makeup, facial hair, furniture, cars, landmarks, etc... those can all be used to make an educated guess. Although we can't see all of that in this image.

Beyond clues in the image content itself, nailing a specific creation date of a scanned image will be difficult. Someone might have an idea of the film used if it was shot on film, but that isn't a home run either.

Answer (score 1):

This jpeg is unfortunately so lossy that it probably isn't going to be helpful for analysing things like film grain or fading.  Even then, it would only give an idea of the film used, not necessarily how old the image is.  It would tell you how old it couldn't be, but not much more.

With the actual paper photo, a little bit more might be able to be determined by how the pigments have faded if the storage of the image is well known, but without a lot of details, actually analysing the content of the image is your best bet, just like dpollitt already went in to.